# How to map filter options from ODataQueryOptions to RestRequest

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to be able to convert from [ODataQueryOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataqueryoptions(v=vs.118).aspx) to [RestRequest](http://restsharp.org/) in order to be able to issue a RestRequest with specified filters, and have created the following helper class:

```
public static class ODataQueryFilterToRestClient
{
    public static RestRequest Map(ODataQueryOptions odataQuery)
    {
        var restRequest = new RestRequest();

        if (odataQuery.Filter != null)
        {
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter(@"$filter", odataQuery.Filter.RawValue);
        }

        if (odataQuery.Top != null)
        {
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter(@"$top", odataQuery.Top.RawValue);
        }

        if (odataQuery.Skip != null)
        {
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter(@"$skip", odataQuery.Skip.RawValue);
        }

        if (odataQuery.OrderBy != null)
        {
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter(@"$orderby", odataQuery.OrderBy.RawValue);
        }
        //etc
        return restRequest;
    }
}
```

Given that OdataQueryOptions supports the following:

[image]

**Is there a simpler way to make the conversion between ODataQueryOptions to RestClient, or another rest client proxy?**

On a side note, I don't know **if there's a better way to accept parameters through a controller than ODataQueryOptions?**

Comment: As I understand, you want call another API on a different server. If that is the case than you should probably check the documentation of that API. If it is not OData I doubt that it will accept $filter, $select.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current approach?It's just a method call.How do you imagine something simpler?

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct support of `ODataQueryOptions` in `RestSharp`.

There are other clients designed specifically for querying with `OData`, e.g. [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki). However it also doesn't operate with `ODataQueryOptions` for requests, providing fluent API.

Overall `ODataQueryOptions` is rather used on a server-side in `OData` compatible RESTful APIs. Clients (including `RestSharp`) just use their regular syntax to provide the data for request.

So answering your question (Is there a simpler way...) - No, there is not.

However your conversion method looks nice and pretty simple. If I had to make a call with `RestSharp` for given `ODataQueryOptions`, I'd do this exactly in the same way.